# MySql 8.0.0 and Docker compose problems

Tags: mysql, docker

I have specified in my docker-compose.yml the version of MySql 8.0.0 and I am having some issues (that I did not have not specifying the version). What is wrong?

Below you can find my docker-compose.yml and error logs:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
db:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_USER: symfony
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
php:
    build: ./php-fpm
    ports:
        - "9000:9001"
    volumes:
        - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony:cached
        - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/var/log:cached
    links:
        - db
    extra_hosts:
        - "docker-host.localhost:127.0.0.1"
        - "symfony.localhost:172.24.0.5"
nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx:cached
        - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony:cached

elk:
    image: willdurand/elk
    ports:
        - "81:80"
    volumes:
        - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash:cached
        - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns:cached
        - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/var/log:cached
        - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx:cached
```

and logs:

```
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.129419Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with 
implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use -- 
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for 
more details).
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.130523Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 8.0.0- 
dmr) starting as process 1 ...
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.134864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux 
native AIO
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.135137Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is 
disabled.
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.136567Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE 
support available
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.136614Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and 
rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.136620Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event 
mutexes
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.136623Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin 
__atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.136626Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed 
tables use zlib 1.2.3
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.137151Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Number of 
pools: 1
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.137390Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU 
crc32 instructions
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.139057Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing 
buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1     | libnuma: Warning: /sys not mounted or invalid. Assuming one 
node: No such file or directory
db_1     | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1     | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1     | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1     | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.150384Z 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed 
initialization of buffer pool
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.152938Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld 
execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be 
changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.169513Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unsupported 
redo log format. The redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.15. Please 
follow the instructions at 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-downgrading.html
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.169587Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin 
initialization aborted with error Generic error
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.774335Z 1 [ERROR] Failed to initialize 
DD Storage Engine
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.774965Z 0 [ERROR] Data Dictionary 
initialization failed.
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.775132Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
db_1     |
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.775198Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.775614Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 
'InnoDB'
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.775986Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 
'MyISAM'
 db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.776099Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 
'CSV'
db_1     | 2019-06-25T11:12:28.779905Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown 
complete
db_1     |
docker-symfony4-udggui_db_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you did not specify the version as `image: mysql`, it will use the latest version. At this time the question was raised, it's `8.0.16`, see [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

When you specify the version as `image: mysql:8.0.0`, you just use an old version of mysql.

Unfortunately, this version not compatible with new docker as next:

> The server use mbind for NUMA (non-uniform memory access) operations, but Docker blocks this access by default. It's possible to provide a custom profile that allows it, but the syntax of the profile files has changed across Docker versions, so it's kind of messy.

That means, at old time this image work, but now docker upgraded, the mysql image should do corresponding changes. And, `8.0.16` which currently the latest, already made this fix, so it's ok. Detail refers to next discussion:

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/303

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/422

Comment: I currently use the version 
8.0.23 and I have the same problem, besides an excessive memory consumption, do you recommend me to change to MariaDB?